# How to implement billing for a desktop app

Tags: database, windows, stripe-payments, desktop, billing

I have a windows desktop application (actually it is cross platform) that users can sign up and i store auth data like mail and username and password in a mysql database. Now i want to add a subscription fee on a monthly basis for using the app so that i am thinking of implementing a payment gateway like stripe gateway by which the user pay the subscription fee and i then store in database that the user is subscribed and check that every month . Is this a good approach .
Is there any better idea.i want the best approach in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Stripe doesn't make any desktop client libraries, so your best bet for the payment part is to handle that part on the web using [something like Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder).